# Large object postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, servidor, script

Alguém conhece alguma função ou script substituto a lo_export do postgres, meu problema é que estou migrando as bases de dados para um servidor separado da aplicação e não gostaria de utilizar compartilhamento de pastas entre servidores para poder vizualizar as imagens.

Comment: Já avaliou a possibilidade de utilizar o tipo de dados `bytea`?